# How to check if logged in via 3rd party service in Meteor framework?

Tags: meteor

How do you check whether a user is logged in via third party (Google, Facebook, ...) in the Meteor framework? Also, is this possible from the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it. On the Server side you would have a function like `Accounts.onCreateUser((options, user) => {... })`.
If you already publish minimum data of the user, you can add a key using `onCreateUser` and save something like: `loginVia: "email"` or `"FB"` etc. Then you publish that key or get its value with a method.

The straight forward solution is to check if the social service exists if look for a particular service.
For Example:

```js
const isFBUser: Meteor.users.find({ _id :....  }, { 'services.facebook': { $exists: true } }).count() // results in 1 record or 0 records = true / false
```

of if you want to know if the user is coming via email and not third party you can check for emails

```js
const isThirdParty = Meteor.users.find({_id: ...}, emails: { $exists: true })
```

It is pretty common to also use a merge accounts system so that someone coming from FB with the email gigi@gmail.com will letter be allowed to log in to you app with the email instead of the social account. In this case,  you would need to eventually save the source of the last login.

I'll leave here for you part of my onCreateUser as example of how to pull data out of a 3rd party user and save it in the use profile. On the same lines you can save the 3rd party source (as suggested above)

```js
if (user.services) {
    const fb = user.services.facebook
    const google = user.services.google

    let avatar = null
    let fbi = null  // I use this to keep a record of the FB user Id
    let ggli = null // // I use this to keep a record of the Google user Id 

    if (fb) {
      /**
       * I upload to S3 and I don't wait for a response. A little risky...
       */
      put_from_url(`https://graph.facebook.com/${fb.id}/picture?width=500&height=500`, `avatar/${fb.id}.jpg`, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Could not upload FB photo to S3, ', err)
        } else {
          // console.log(res)
        }
      })

      user.profile = extend(user.profile, {
        firstName: fb.first_name,
        lastName: fb.last_name,
        email: fb.email,
        displayName: fb.name,
        gender: startCase(toLower(fb.gender)),
        avatar: `${fb.id}.jpg`
      })
      avatar = `${fb.id}.jpg`
      fbi = fb.id
      roles = ['user', 'social']
    }

    if (google) {
      /**
       * I upload to S3 and I don't wait for a response. A little risky...
       */
      put_from_url(google.picture + '?sz=500', `avatar/${google.id}.jpg`, err => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Could not upload Google photo to S3, ', err)
        }
      })

      user.profile = extend(user.profile, {
        firstName: google.given_name,
        lastName: google.family_name,
        email: google.email,
        displayName: google.name,
        gender: startCase(toLower(google.gender)),
        avatar: `${google.id}.jpg`
      })
      avatar = `${google.id}.jpg`
      ggli = google.id
      roles = ['user', 'social']
    }

    /**
     * Create a slug for each user. Requires a display name for all users.
     */

    let slug
    slug = Meteor.call('/app/create/slug', user.profile.displayName, 'user')
```

Also please check the user object structure:

[image]

And check this out. Users via 3rd party don't have the email field so you can check its existence.

[image]